# How to distinguish between Rsync and SSH access in a “.bashrc” script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal, rsync

I have the following `.bashrc` on a remote host:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 DEFAULT=$PS1
 PS1="\h:\w\$ "
 source ~/.bash_aliases
 if [[ $(hostname -s) = host_name ]]; then
    source /path/somescript.sh
 fi
```

When I use `rsync` with the remote host as destination, the command within the `if`-`fi` is executed. I do not want to execute this command when I use remote host as a destination of `rsync`. I want to execute this command only when I access the remote host with `ssh`.

Is there a variable to differentiate between  these two cases?

FWIW, I get warning when running `rsync`, that I do not get in `ssh`:

```
/path/somescript.sh: line 1: module: command not found
```

Comment: well, rsync uses ssh for remote connections, so you will have to look for additional criteria upon which to filter in your if statement. do the rsync jobs run as a different user for instance?

Comment: @FrankThomas same user. I have edited the question with an example of warning that I am getting

Comment: `/path/somescript.sh: line 1: module: command not found` That basically means whatever is in the first line of the script `/path/somescript.sh` cannot be found. If you are running via Rsync, your user `$PATH` variable doesn’t get set so whatever command in there… Unless it has the full path to the command will not know where that command is. Like `time` as a logged in user gives you output because the `$PATH` variable is set. Without it, the only way to get output is to call it as `/usr/bin/time`. Maybe that is the answer to your question? Set of `$PATH` is set?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 module-> module environment. I do not need to run that script when I access with `rsync`. I would like to not run that script.

Comment: I myself (when presented with a dilemma like this) would add an environment dump to text for each login.  Save them off.. then diff them and you will have your answer without asking someone else. :)  This is what @FrankThomas is eluding to.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas that sounds good. I was not aware of this. How do I do it? A clarifying instruction would be helpful.

Comment: OK.. but it isn't an answer to your question.. just a way to teach you to fish.  Add something like `printenv >~/mydump.txt` to the top of your `.bashrc`. Login one way and rename mydump.txt to sshlogin_env.txt (or whatever).. login the other way and rename the file again.  Revert the env dump line from your `.bashrc`.  Diff the two files and you will see differences that you can use to determine which method was used to login.

Comment: “I do not need to run that script when I access with `rsync`.” Exactly. Then setup some check at the very beginning of the script such as `if [[ -z $PATH ]]; then exit; fi`. That basically means if `$PATH` is empty, exit. And if `$PATH` is not empty? That doesn’t get triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually sounds like you actually want to distinguish between *interactive* and *batch* SSH access.

Rsync still goes over SSH – as does SFTP, and Git, and Borg, and several other tools, and even `ssh example.host some_command`. What they have in common is that they're non-interactive, and do not allocate a tty – all of them want SSH to provide a clean data tunnel, and all equally have no use whatsoever for $PS1 or bash_aliases. There's nothing really special about Rsync here.

To distinguish these two modes, add a `$-` check near the top of your ~/.bashrc:

```
[[ $- == *i* ]] || return 0
```

Most importantly, this should go before *anything* that would produce output. Usually it can just be done as the first thing in your ~/.bashrc (except perhaps after setting environment variables like PATH).

Comment: More information: [Why does bashrc check whether the current shell is interactive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257571/108618)